# org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException:

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, kerberos

I working on spark streaming job in which incoming stream join with existing hive table. I have created a singleton hiveContext. When hiveContext fetch the table data from hive, spark give warning and after few day warning converts into error.

> 18/03/10 15:55:28 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$buildInternalScan$1$$anon$1: Input split: ParquetInputSplit{part: hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/iot.db/iotdevice/part-r-00000-931d1d81-af03-41a4-b659-81a883131289.gz.parquet start: 0 end: 5695 length: 5695 hosts: []}
>
> 18/03/10 15:55:28 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:svc-ra-iotloaddev (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
>   18/03/10 15:55:28 WARN kms.LoadBalancingKMSClientProvider: KMS provider at [https://iotserver9009.kd.iotserver.com:16000/kms/v1/] threw an IOException [org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]!!

It will stop the job after some day.

Here is code for creating hivecontext

```
@transient private var instance: HiveContext = _
 def getHiveContext(sparkContext: SparkContext, propertiesBroadcast: Broadcast[Properties]): HiveContext = {
        synchronized {

  val configuration = new Configuration
  configuration.addResource("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml")
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration)
  UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser.setAuthenticationMethod(AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS)

  val secure = propertiesBroadcast.value.getProperty("kerberosSecurity").toBoolean
  if (instance == null) {

    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(
      propertiesBroadcast.value.getProperty("hadoop.kerberos.principal"), sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.yarn.keytab"))
      .doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[HiveContext]() {
        @Override
        def run(): HiveContext = {
          System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", propertiesBroadcast.value.getProperty("hive.metastore.uris"));
          if (secure) {
            System.setProperty("hive.metastore.sasl.enabled", "true")
            System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file", sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.yarn.keytab"))
            System.setProperty("hive.security.authorization.enabled", "false")
            System.setProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal", propertiesBroadcast.value.getProperty("hive.metastore.kerberos.principal"))
            System.setProperty("hive.metastore.execute.setugi", "true")
          }

          instance = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
          instance.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true")

          instance.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
          instance.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
          instance.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
          instance
        }
      })

  }

  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(
    propertiesBroadcast.value.getProperty("hadoop.kerberos.principal"), sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.yarn.keytab"))
    .doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[HiveContext]() {
      @Override
      def run(): HiveContext = {
        instance
      }
    })

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you create your own private Kerberos credentials instead of letting Spark handle this nasty stuff?? Including the **renewal** of the Kerberos TGT...?

Comment: I have tried without loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI methode but getting same error . Do you have some code snippet ?

Comment: Recommended reading about Kerberos ticket renewal w/ Hadoop libs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop (including pointers to other posts)

Comment: Recommended reading about the shortcomings of Spark-Hive integration w/ Kerberos and "cluster" mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477155/hive-site-missing-when-using-spark-submit-yarn-cluster-mode

Comment: Recommended reading about Hadoop and Kerberos: the GitBook by Steve Loughran (HortonWorks) _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the madness beyond the gate"_

Comment: Bottom line: it's complicated. You have to understand (a little bit) how it works, and possibly dig into the source code. You can't just paste a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve these problems running `kinit` before running the command.

The command `klist` will display your valid kerberos tickets.